# Restart a MassTransit Saga

Tags: masstransit, automatonymous

In my application, user can trigger updates for a specific resource. When that happens, an `UpdateInitiated` event is sent.

A MassTransit Saga is initiated based on that event, and it triggers a series of other events until it considers itself done and finalizes.

While an update is ongoing, users can make changes to the resource and request a new update. I'm trying to figure out how I can abort the ongoing Saga and create a new instance, when a new `UpdateInitiated` event is sent for the same resource.

Two approaches I'm thinking about

1. Correlate on ResourceId. So the initial Saga would get the second `UpdateInitiated` event as well. But then I don't know how to reset the saga (and stop listening for events related to the previous update).
2. Use `CorrelatedBy<Guid>` (as I am doing now). This would create a new Saga for the new update event. But then I don't know how to cancel the initial Saga.

Is there a way to listen to arbitrary events in a Saga? Like: "Listen to all `UpdatedInitiated` events even if they don't correlate, and cancel the current Saga if there is an event with the matching ResourceId".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that it's possible to register for events where you correlate on something other than the `CorrelationId`. In my use case, I want to abort an ongoing saga if there is a new event kicking off a new saga, for the same `ResourceId`.

What I did was this:

```
// Listen to update initiated events for the same ResourceId
Event(() => UpdateInitiated , e => e
    .CorrelateBy((instance, context) =>
        instance.CurrentState != 2 &&
        instance.CorrelationId != context.Message.CorrelationId &&
        instance.ResourceId == context.Message.ResourceId
    )
    .SelectId(x => NewId.NextGuid()));

// Finalize this saga if there is a newer one for the same ResourceId
DuringAny(
    When(UpdateInitiated)
        .Then(context => Log.Information("Saga aborted due to newer update initiated by {correlationId}", context.Data.CorrelationId))
        .Finalize());
```